# Web component Light DOM slot equivalent for injecting dynamic content into specific element

Tags: web-component

Im struggling to do something that seems like it should be simple. I am creating my first web component and it cannot be within the shadowDOM. I need it to receive some dynamic content and inject it into the correct div like so:

```
<component>
  <div id="one"><!-- Dynamic Content ends up here --></div>
  <div id="two">...</div>
</component>
```

This is simple using slots in shadowDOM, why is it proving difficult in lightDOM?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: receive from where? ``<slot>`` only works in shadowDOM. Please add a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is essentially about using `slots` without Shadow DOM. Unfortunately, there is no out-of-box solution for this problem. You can use combination of [`<template>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) tag and component props:

```html
<component>
  <template>
      <div id="one"><!-- Dynamic Content ends up here --></div>
      <div id="two">...</div>
  </template>
</component>
```

And, then for each instance of the `<component />`, you will clone the template using `cloneNode` method. And, then you append this Node as a child of your custom component. You can augment the DOM however you like.

Now, second part of the equation is adding the dynamic content to the `div#one` and `div#two`. For this purpose, you should declare the two `props` over the component and the caller will pass the content. The web component will then append that content via `DocumentFragment`, `innerHTML` or other DOM APIs. This is roughly similar to what vDOM based frameworks like `React`, `Vue` do. The only difference is instead of passing real DOM, it passes virtual tree as a `children` or `render` prop.

So, without a proper framework, this is a lot of work. I would recommend you consider using Shadow DOM and keep the Shadow Root `open`.